# Cygwin: C standard library does not support <uchar.h>?

Tags: unicode, cygwin, libc

Scenario:

```
$ echo "#include <uchar.h>" | gcc -xc - -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: uchar.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 xxx 3.3.4(0.341/5/3) 2022-01-31 19:35 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Does is mean that C standard library does not support `<uchar.h>`?

---

UPDATE. From Brian Inglis:

> Nobody else has noticed or mentioned those in the last decade, so there
> may not be (any updates), as volunteers have limited time and their own interests and
> priorities.
>
> Given that newlib is a freestanding implementation, and gcc does not
> provide that header, those definitions or declarations, these are
> considered platform implementation issues, which someone supporting that
> platform has to decide if they will provide and support.
>
> ICU provides uchar.h which Cygwin libicu-devel maintainer installs under
> /usr/include/unicode/ with Unicode licence under
> /usr/share/icu//LICENSE.
> You could pull those two files from the ICU distro for use in your work.
>
> It also is/will be available on glibc platforms which support it.
> Remember that GNU products are GPL licensed with possibly undesirable
> requirements for most commercial products.
>
> Similarly, TIME_UTC may not be available on some newlib
> platforms/targets, so it will be up to platform and/or target
> maintainers to decide if they can support it, and provide implementations.
>
> I don't know what your host platform is, your newlib target, or what
> POSIX time.h CLOCK_/clock_... support is available, but you may wish to
> use that instead, until someone can provide the ISO C equivalent in
> newlib under a BSD licence.
>
> You may also wish to look at what is available in *BSD sources.

Comment: With a few exceptions, gcc doesn't provide library headers. On a typical Linux system, `uchar.h` is provided by glibc. Cygwin's newlib apparently doesn't provide `uchar.h`.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it is about the C standard library, not GCC. The title and description is updated.

Comment: @KeithThompson Extra: I always wanted to ask: if GCC (Clang too?) doesn't know in advance whether its accompanying C standard library is conforming, then why it defines in advance `__STDC__` to 1? See also: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53132.

Comment: @KeithThompson : But gcc should provide the headers required by the ANSI standard. uchar.h is part of the C11 standard, and the OP explicitly requested `-std=c11`. Shouldn't this be regarded an implementation bug (lacking standard conformance)?

Comment: @user1934428 As I understand, there is so-called "implementation" or "C implementation". It includes C compiler and C standard library. GCC is a C compiler. The `<uchar.h>` is defined in section 7 (Library) of C11. Hence, the library is required (for conforming hosted implementation) to provide `<uchar.h>`. Also: if GCC itself (i.e. w/o library) is not the (full) implementation, then why it defines `__STDC__` to `1` (indicates conforming implementation). Full implementation != partial implementation.

Comment: @user1934428 Not to forget that per C11 `uchar.h` need not be a physical file.

Comment: @user1934428 A C compiler is not a C implementation. An implementation consists of a compiler, a runtime library, and other components, which must all work together. On my Ubuntu system, the implementation uses gcc and glibc; glibc provides `uchar.h`. On my Cygwin system, the compiler is gcc and the library is newlib; newlib does not provide `uchar.h`. Yes, that means that the implementation under Cygwin is non-conforming.

Comment: @pmor Yes, strictly speaking a compiler's definition of `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__` is making a claim about the conformance of the implementation, not just of the compiler. But given that the gcc/newlib implementation on Cygwin is non-conforming due to its lack of `uchar.h`, it can do anything it likes. The C standard does not and cannot impose any requirements on non-conforming implementations. (Tweaking gcc to define `__STDC__` in a way that reflects the conformance of the full implementation is difficult; there could be a newlib update tomorrow that adds support for `uchar.h`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson : I basically agree, but since the gcc manpage says abut `-std c11`:  _This standard is substantially completely supported, modulo bugs, floating-point issues ... and the optional Annexes K  and L_, and `gcc` is a component of the C implementation,  I think filing a bug report could help. It does not mean that the Cygwin developers **will** fix it (they also dropped, for instance, a cruicial library from their Ruby distribution and won't fix it), but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, defining `__STDC__` to 1 while being non-conforming implementation is OK. We can say that in this case the purpose of defining `__STDC__` to 1 _in advance_ (i.e. w/o knowledge whether the libc is conforming) is to show an _intent_ of being conforming. The similar story is in `stdc-predef.h`: `glibc's intent is to support the IEC 559 math functionality`.

Comment: @pmor I don't agree that it's ok. `__STDC==1` can reasonably be interpreted as a *claim* that the implementation conforms to the C standard, specifically to the edition specified by the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`. If, for example, `__STDC_VERISON__` indicates C11 conformance and `uchar.h` doesn't exist, then the claim is a lie. It's fundamentally no different than defining `__STDC__` and not supporting structs. The problem is that this is unenforceable; the standard obviously cannot constrain non-conforming implementations, including those that lie about their conformance.

Comment: @KeithThompson Under "OK" I meant "the standard is not violated", because "the standard obviously cannot constrain non-conforming implementations". I understand `__STDC__ == 1` as "_maybe_ conforming implementation". Also the documentation is expected to specify whether the implementation is conforming. (If it isn't, then what are the deviations, etc.) Example: despite of documenting that "`clock` [function does not strictly conform to ISO C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/clock?view=msvc-170)" msvc defines `__STDC__` to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `libicu-devel` package
the header will be under:

```
/usr/include/unicode/uchar.h
```

Comment: I just tried this. It creates `/usr/include/unicode/uchar.h` but not `/usr/include/uchar.h`, and the error in the question still occurs.

Comment: @KeithThompson See UPD.

Comment: @pmor Might I suggest expanding that to UPDATE. I just wasted some time (not much) trying to figure out what "UPD" stands for.

Comment: @KeithThompson OK. I didn't know that newlib is a freestanding implementation. It bothers me a bit because GCC on Cygwin defines both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_HOSTED__` to 1.

Comment: @pmor newlib is not a freestanding implementation, because it's not an implementation. It can be *part* of an implementation. Nothing in the newlib source tree suggests that it's meant to be freestanding, though the [home page](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) says it's "a C library intended for use on embedded systems". As far as I know, the gcc/newlib implementation on Cygwin is intended to be hosted, though it may be missing some required features. newlib provides the vast majority of the features required for hosted implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson Re: "it's not an implementation": yes, of course. Re: "it may be missing some required features": in 3 cases I could not compile my code on GCC on Cygwin: 1) `<uchar.h>`, 2) `timespec_get` and `TIME_UTC`, 3) `CMPLX `.