# Cygwin: C standard library does not support TIME_UTC and timespec_get?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, libc, time.h

Sample code (t667c.c, taken from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    char buff[100];
    strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%D %T", gmtime(&ts.tv_sec));
    printf("Current time: %s.%09ld UTC\n", buff, ts.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ gcc t667c.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t667c.c: In function ‘main’:
t667c.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘timespec_get’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    7 |     timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
t667c.c:7:23: error: ‘TIME_UTC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    7 |     timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
t667c.c:7:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Extra:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 xxx 3.3.4(0.341/5/3) 2022-01-31 19:35 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Does it mean that `TIME_UTC` and `timespec_get` are not supported?

---

UPD. See [UPD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71324524/1778275) in the similar question.

Comment: Since this is not your first question regarding cygwin: Cygwin seems to use newlib as libc implementation, see https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.glibc. That is a very minimal implementation of the C standard library. I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't implement a lot of especially the newer features. The readme even says that it is an "ANSI C library" (https://sourceware.org/newlib/README).

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks! How to determine the version of newlib? Is there a corresponding macro?

Comment: From what I can tell `__NEWLIB__` and `__NEWLIB_MINOR__`. But I don't know how heavily modified the cygwin version is. Repository seems to be here: https://cygwin.com/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=summary

Comment: Put all your options before your source files. E.G. `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra t667c.c`, since some options are handled left to right.